# sbt error while installing Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I am installing Spark 2.1.0 on ubuntu 16.04.1 and getting this error(**/usr/share/sbt-launcher-packaging/bin/sbt-launch-lib.bash: line 41: 1339 Killed "$@"**). I have installed Scala and Java( using Java 7, although Java 8 is installed as well). See below the output:

```
/spark-2.1.0# sbt clean assembly

[info] Loading project definition from /root/spark-2.1.0/project
[info] Set current project to spark-parent (in build file:/root/spark-2.1.0/)
[success] Total time: 1 s, completed Jan 13, 2017 7:39:18 PM
[success] created output: /root/spark-2.1.0/external/flume-assembly/target
[success] created output: /root/spark-2.1.0/external/kafka-0-8-assembly/target
[success] created output: /root/spark-2.1.0/external/kafka-0-10-assembly/target
[info] Updating {file:/root/spark-2.1.0/}tags...
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Updating {file:/root/spark-2.1.0/}network-common...
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Updating {file:/root/spark-2.1.0/}launcher...
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Updating {file:/root/spark-2.1.0/}unsafe...
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Updating {file:/root/spark-2.1.0/}streaming-flume-sink...
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Updating {file:/root/spark-2.1.0/}network-shuffle...
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Updating {file:/root/spark-2.1.0/}core...
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
[info] Done updating.
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
[warn] Here are some of the libraries that were evicted:
[warn]  * commons-net:commons-net:2.2 -> 3.1
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
[info] Updating {file:/root/spark-2.1.0/}streaming...
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Updating {file:/root/spark-2.1.0/}streaming-flume...
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Updating {file:/root/spark-2.1.0/}streaming-kafka-0-8...
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Updating {file:/root/spark-2.1.0/}streaming-kafka-0-10...
[info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty.websocket#websocket-client;9.2.12.v20150709 .                                                                             [info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty.websocket#websocket-common;9.2.12.v20150709 .                                                                             [info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Updating {file:/root/spark-2.1.0/}streaming-flume-assembly...
[info] Resolving org.glassfish.jersey.containers#jersey-container-servlet;2.22.2                                                                             [info] Resolving org.glassfish.jersey.containers#jersey-container-servlet-core;2                                                                             [info] Resolving com.fasterxml.jackson.module#jackson-module-scala_2.11;2.6.5 ..                                                                             [info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
[info] Done updating.
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
[warn] Here are some of the libraries that were evicted:
[warn]  * commons-net:commons-net:2.2 -> 3.1
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
[info] Updating {file:/root/spark-2.1.0/}streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly...
[info] Resolving org.glassfish.jersey.containers#jersey-container-servlet;2.22.2                                                                             [info] Resolving org.glassfish.jersey.containers#jersey-container-servlet-core;2                                                                             [info] Resolving com.fasterxml.jackson.module#jackson-module-scala_2.11;2.6.5 ..                                                                             [info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Updating {file:/root/spark-2.1.0/}streaming-kafka-0-10-assembly...
[info] Resolving org.glassfish.jersey.containers#jersey-container-servlet;2.22.2                                                                             [info] Resolving org.glassfish.jersey.containers#jersey-container-servlet-core;2                                                                             [info] Resolving com.fasterxml.jackson.module#jackson-module-scala_2.11;2.6.5 ..                                                                             [info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
[info] Done updating.
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tr                                                                             ee.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tr                                                                             ee.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
[success] created output: /root/spark-2.1.0/external/flume/target
[success] created output: /root/spark-2.1.0/common/unsafe/target
[success] created output: /root/spark-2.1.0/common/network-common/target
[success] created output: /root/spark-2.1.0/core/target
[success] created output: /root/spark-2.1.0/common/tags/target
[info] Avro compiler using stringType=CharSequence
[info] Compiling Avro IDL /root/spark-2.1.0/external/flume-sink/src/main/avro/sparkflume.avdl
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
[success] created output: /root/spark-2.1.0/external/flume-sink/target
[success] created output: /root/spark-2.1.0/streaming/target
[success] created output: /root/spark-2.1.0/launcher/target
[success] created output: /root/spark-2.1.0/common/network-shuffle/target
[success] created output: /root/spark-2.1.0/external/kafka-0-8/target
[success] created output: /root/spark-2.1.0/external/kafka-0-10/target
[info] Compiling 2 Scala sources and 9 Java sources to /root/spark-2.1.0/common/tags/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[info] Packaging /root/spark-2.1.0/common/tags/target/scala-2.11/spark-tags_2.11-2.1.0.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info] Compiling 6 Scala sources and 3 Java sources to /root/spark-2.1.0/external/flume-sink/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[info] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[info] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[info] Compiling 15 Java sources to /root/spark-2.1.0/launcher/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[info] Compiling 16 Java sources to /root/spark-2.1.0/common/unsafe/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[info] Compiling 65 Java sources to /root/spark-2.1.0/common/network-common/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[info] Packaging /root/spark-2.1.0/common/unsafe/target/scala-2.11/spark-unsafe_2.11-2.1.0.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info] Packaging /root/spark-2.1.0/launcher/target/scala-2.11/spark-launcher_2.11-2.1.0.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info] Packaging /root/spark-2.1.0/external/flume-sink/target/scala-2.11/spark-streaming-flume-sink_2.11-2.1.0.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info] Packaging /root/spark-2.1.0/common/network-common/target/scala-2.11/spark-network-common_2.11-2.1.0.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info] Compiling 19 Java sources to /root/spark-2.1.0/common/network-shuffle/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[info] Packaging /root/spark-2.1.0/common/network-shuffle/target/scala-2.11/spark-network-shuffle_2.11-2.1.0.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info] Compiling 474 Scala sources and 75 Java sources to /root/spark-2.1.0/core/target/scala-2.11/classes...
**/usr/share/sbt-launcher-packaging/bin/sbt-launch-lib.bash: line 41:  1339 Killed                  "$@**"
```

Comment: There is no signs of error here, look like you've just killed process manually

Comment: This also looks like you are building Spark from source which I would expect to take longer than using one of the pre-built versions.